# Grub2 won't show any graphical menu

Tags: grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu on my system, and since my previous grub2 installation was messy, I decided to reinstall grub2 in this ubuntu partition.

Anyway it didn't totally work : grub-install didn't give any error, yet on reboot, grub doesn't show its menu, but only its command line.

I can manage to boot all the OSes on my computer from there, but it's something I'd like to avoid in the long term (typing 4 lines of code, with an american keymap is slightly slower than scrolling to a specific entry).

I have tried various settings of GRUB_TERMINAL, but I didn't get any change.
There is no error message that I can see before the command line prompt, only grub command introduction message.

Here is my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` :

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.0.1-3.fc14.i686 (on /dev/sda5)"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=800x600x24
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=fr_FR
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="$1"
    if [ "$1" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae (mode de dépannage)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
    echo    'Chargement de Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae (mode de dépannage)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
    echo    'Chargement de Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b34ab83e-0c3a-4671-bcd5-786b37622389
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9CDC9835DC980C20
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod fat
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8299-11DD
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.0.1-3.fc14.i686 (on /dev/sda5)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3065baea-4365-4203-876f-6cf898dcd3a6
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-3.fc14.i686 root=/dev/sda5 ro quiet
}
menuentry "Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.0.1-3.fc14.i686 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda5)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3065baea-4365-4203-876f-6cf898dcd3a6
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-3.fc14.i686 root=/dev/sda5 ro single
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

and here is my `/etc/default/grub` :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.0.1-3.fc14.i686 (on /dev/sda5)"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="800x600x24"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Is there any part of the configuration process that I missed? Grub has always worked out of the box in the past, at least when installed in ubuntu, so that's highly possible.

Thanks in advance,

Edit : Using aptitude to redownload and reinstall grub fixed the issue now. But still I'd like to know what was causing the issue.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @Suhaib : As I said in my edit, I solved it by reinstalling grub. The problem didn't appear again, so I still don't know what was the cause. At the moment, I don't think this question is likely to help future visitors, including you, sorry.

Comment: oh, oK. Can you please post it as a seperate solution and accept it please :-)

Comment: The question is about the cause of the problem, rather than its solution. However, I understand it's hard to investigate an autosolved problem, so I'll just accept the answer about how to debug grub, should the problem reappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to debug `grub2` issues looking at the generated `grub.cfg`. The first thing to try when having such kind of issues with `grub2` is to purge its packages and reinstall them. with it's "plain" configuration, `grub2` is likely to work well.

However, to effectively debug `grub2` issues, it's advisable to run it within `qemu`:

`sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; qemu -hda /dev/sdx`

This make the debug process faster (no need to reboot) and at the same time slows down `grub2` allowing to see error messages otherwise too quick to be read at boot.